# Zooming core plot along Y-axis and X-axis Independently

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.3, core-plot

I am Using the below code to scroll my core plot along X-axis Y-axis and zoom. Its working fine. But I when i zoom my core plot, it zooms in both the directions. I want the plot to zoom along X if I pinch along x-direction and zoom Y if pinch along Y-direction. Can someone help me with this please.

```
-(CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)displacement
{
    return CGPointMake(displacement.x, displacement.y);
}

-(CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    // Adjust axis to keep them in view at the left and bottom;
    // adjust scale-labels to match the scroll.

    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)self.hostView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
    if (coordinate == CPTCoordinateX) {
        axisSet.yAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = newRange.location;
    }

    else {
        axisSet.yAxis.titleLocation = CPTDecimalFromFloat(newRange.locationDouble +                                                  (newRange.lengthDouble / 2.0F));
    }

    return newRange;
}
```

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/q/3559577/1487063

Comment: Although I'm actually confused about what you want to happen if you only zoom in one direction... Will you change the ratios? That's not really zooming and you'll probably need to redraw.

Comment: Is it possible to do without using pinchgesture as core plot itself allows the detection of pinch

Comment: yeah sorry for the confusion but have to redraw if I pinch it along X-axis making the bars wider and taller if pinch along y-axis

Comment: My core plot line graph should be able to work like a shinobi line chart

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to keep the axes and title in the correct position is to use the `axisConstraints` for the axes and leave the `titleLocation` at it's default of NAN. This will relieve your delegate of responsibility for updating those items and you can focus on the zooming.

Of those two delegate methods, you only need `-plotSpace:willChangePlotRangeTo:forCoordinate:`. The other one is only called when scrolling.

Decide whether you want to allow the zoom to happen in x or y (see the links in the comments on the original question). Check the `coordinate` parameter in the delegate method; return the `newRange` to allow the zoom to happen or `[space plotRangeForCoordinate:coordinate]` to restore the original range and prevent zooming.

If you need to use your own gesture recognizer to detect the pinch angle, set `allowPinchScaling` to NO on the hosting view to disable the built-in recognizer. Add your own recognizer to the hosting view. In the handler method, decide which axis to scale (if any) and adjust the appropriate plot range accordingly. If you do it this way, you don't need a plot space delegate at all.

Comment: I want the zoom to happen in both in X and Y but independently, meaning if i pinch along x-axis the x axis must zoom and of i pinch along Y the height of the bar must increase.

Answer (score 0):

I am calculating the change in X and Y coordinates using UIPinchGestureRecognizer and then determining which direction the plot range should change(either X or Y). Its working fine but It is not as smooth as regular zoom, and it responds late. Can someone suggest me a better way to do this

```
- (void)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
       if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){

        CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:hostView];
       NSLog(@"Sender value %f %f", translation.x,translation.y );
        initialX = translation.x;
        initialY = translation.y;        
        return;   
} 
else if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){
                NSLog(@"inside else");
        CGPoint currentTouchLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:hostView];
        NSLog(@"currentTouchLocation = %f and  %f and ",currentTouchLocation.x, currentTouchLocation.y);
            finalX = currentTouchLocation.x;
            finalY = currentTouchLocation.y;
                  }
}
-(CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate
{
    float x = fabsf(finalX - initialX) ;
    float y = fabsf(finalY - initialY);
    NSLog(@"pinch x = %f  pinch y = %f", x, y);
      CPTPlotRange *updatedRange = nil;

    if (x > y) {
        switch ( coordinate ) {
            case CPTCoordinateX:
                NSLog(@"x is greater than y change x-range");

                if (newRange.locationDouble < 0.0F ) {
                    CPTMutablePlotRange *mutableRange = [[newRange mutableCopy] autorelease];
                  mutableRange.location = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0);
                    updatedRange = mutableRange;
                }
                else {
                    updatedRange = newRange;
               }
                break;
            case CPTCoordinateY:
                NSLog(@"x is greater than y keep y range constant");

                updatedRange = ((CPTXYPlotSpace *)space).yRange;
                break;

        }

            }

    if (x < y) {
        switch ( coordinate ) {
            case CPTCoordinateX:
                NSLog(@"y is greater than x keep x-range constant");

                updatedRange = ((CPTXYPlotSpace *)space).xRange;
                                break;
            case CPTCoordinateY:
                if (newRange.locationDouble < 0.0F) {
                    NSLog(@"y is greater than x increase y range");
                    CPTMutablePlotRange *mutableRange = [[newRange mutableCopy] autorelease];
                  //  mutableRange.location = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0);
                    updatedRange = mutableRange;
                }
                else {
                   updatedRange = newRange;
                }

                break;

        }

    }
    if (x == y) {
        switch ( coordinate ) {
            case CPTCoordinateX:
                NSLog(@"y is equal to  x keep x-range constant");
                updatedRange = ((CPTXYPlotSpace *)space).xRange;
                break;
            case CPTCoordinateY:
                NSLog(@"y is equal to x keep y-range constant");
                //NSLog(@"%d", CPTCoordinateY);
                updatedRange = ((CPTXYPlotSpace *)space).yRange;
                break;

        }

    }



      return updatedRange;



}
```